# Laravel API returning blank/null to RestSharp C#

Tags: c#, laravel

I'm using Laravel as a web API that communicates with my C# app.

I'm trying to make a post request:

```
if ($validate){
        // Store query results in a variable
        $user = Login::where([
                ['BR_ID', $BR_ID],
                ['ClientID', $ClientID],
                ['ClientChkID', $ClientChkID],
                ['LastName', $LastName]
        ])->get();
        // Format contact number
        $ContactNo = $user[0]->ContactNo;
        $otpController = new \App\Http\Controllers\OTPController();
        $phone = $otpController->CheckContactValidity($ContactNo);
        // Append formatted number to laravel's collection object
        $user[0]->ValidContactNo = $phone;

        // send back a response
        return response()->json($user[0], 200);
} else {
        return response()->json(["error"=>"Client does not exist"], 204);
}
```

The code in the if statement works well and returns everything fine. The else part though, does not return anything at all.

Basically, the line `return response()->json(["error"=>"Client does not exist"], 204);` always returns `""` instead of `{ "error":"Client does not exist" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nonsense. 204 status code is a no-content response, so why you want to return something?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success

you can check the response code by

```js
        $.ajax({
        url: "/test",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res) {
        }
        })
        .done(function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(jqXHR.status); // 204
        });
```

Comment: It makes sense now. I thought 204 should still send something since it does in postman.